# Reshape DataFrame categorical values to rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a hard time reorganizing this dataframe. I think I'm supposed to use `pd.pivot_table` or `pd.crosstab`, but I'm not sure how to get the job done.

Here is my DataFrame:

```
vicro = pd.read_csv(vicroURL)
vicro_subset = vicro.ix[:,['P1', 'P10', 'P30', 'P71', 'P82', 'P90']]

In [6]: vicro
vicro         vicroURL      vicro_subset  

In [6]: vicro_subset.head()
Out[6]: 
  P1 P10 P30 P71 P82 P90
0  -   I   -   -   -   M
1  -   I   -   V   T   M
2  -   I   -   V   A   M
3  -   I   -   T   -   M
4  -   -   -   -   A   -
```

What I what to do is take all possible values in this data frame and make them into rows. The new values will be counts. Something that would look like:

```
Out[6]: 
  P1 P10 P30 P71 P82 P90
I  0   4   0   0   0   0
V  0   0   0   2   0   0
A  0   0   0   0   2   0
M  0   0   0   0   0   4
T  0   0   0   1   1   0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Edit:
Elaborating on answer using melt, both helped me understand pandas a bit more, but there was more unknowns for me in "melt" answer:

```
In [8]: melted_df = pd.melt(vicro_subset)

In [9]: melted_df.head()
Out[9]: 
  variable value
0       P1     -
1       P1     -
2       P1     -
3       P1     -
4       P1     -


In [13]: grouped_melt = melted_df.groupby(['variable','value'])['value'].count()
In [14]: grouped_melt.head()
Out[14]: 
variable  value
P1        -        797
          .        269
P10       -        339
          .          1
          F        132


In [15]: unstacked_group = grouped_melt.unstack()

In [16]: unstacked_group.head()
Out[16]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 5 entries, P1 to P82
Data columns:
-       5  non-null values
.       2  non-null values
A       1  non-null values
AITV    1  non-null values
AT      2  non-null values

In [17]: transpose_unstack = unstacked_group.T

In [18]: transpose_unstack.head()
Out[18]: 
variable   P1  P10   P30  P71  P82  P90
value                                  
-         797  339  1005  452  604  634
.         269    1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
A         NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  282  NaN
AITV      NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN    1  NaN
AT        NaN  NaN   NaN    1    2  NaN
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively, something like this should work:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,12).reshape(3,4), 
                                            columns=list('abcd'))

In [4]: print df
   a  b  c  d
0  2  2  3  1
1  0  1  0  2
2  1  3  0  4

In [5]: new = pd.concat([df[col].value_counts() for col in df.columns], axis=1)

In [6]: new.columns = df.columns

In [7]: print new
    a   b   c   d
0   1 NaN   2 NaN
1   1   1 NaN   1
2   1   1 NaN   1
3 NaN   1   1 NaN
4 NaN NaN NaN   1
```

Comment: nice insight... the columns of the new df are actually the value_counts of the original df.

Answer (score 2):

I figured the key is to use `melt`, and a bit of acrobatics afterwards. So here's your DataFrame:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
  P1 P10 P30 P71 P82 P90
0  -   I   -   -   -   M
1  -   I   -   V   T   M
2  -   I   -   V   A   M
3  -   I   -   T   -   M
4  -   -   -   -   A   -
```

Now if you do the following (you might want to step it through in IPython to see the intermediate results):

```
In [22]: pd.melt(df).groupby(['variable', 'value'])['value'].count().unstack().T
.fillna(0)
Out[22]:
variable  P1  P10  P30  P71  P82  P90
value
-          5    1    5    2    2    1
A          0    0    0    0    2    0
I          0    4    0    0    0    0
M          0    0    0    0    0    4
T          0    0    0    1    1    0
V          0    0    0    2    0    0
```

Say you save the result in `df2`, you can then remove the '-' row:

```
In [25]: df2.drop('-')
Out[25]:
variable  P1  P10  P30  P71  P82  P90
value
A          0    0    0    0    2    0
I          0    4    0    0    0    0
M          0    0    0    0    0    4
T          0    0    0    1    1    0
V          0    0    0    2    0    0
```

Comment: excellent. would you mind accepting the answer then? or root's one above, or both if you like...

Comment: I stepped through the large melt method and added it to the above question. Thanks for the help.